# Unable to publish my application on IBM Bluemix server within Eclipse

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

I am unable to publish the application (forked out from git) onto IBM Bluemix. It gives following error message:

> App instance exited with guid e004e29f-3465-4567-baa1-14b9e8fd98fb
>    payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"e004e29f-3465-4567-baa1-14b9e8fd98fb", "version"=>"e1632d29-d1fa-44e7-a8d6-87818e20aa81", "instance"=>"6e2777a7f122433ca92eded24573617f", "index"=>0, **"reason"=>"CRASHED"**, "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1466855016}

I am trying to sync the application on Eclipse IDE, so I can start coding within the IDE and publish the changes.

Comment: Please share the output of the *cf logs <app_name> --recent* command. Can you see any other error there?

Comment: Can you provide the location where this application was forked from?